# SubclassNotFound in RailsAdmin::Main#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error message while I try to run my app

> The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
>   'Direct'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved
>   for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this
>   column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance
>   class or overwrite Expense.inheritance_column to use another column
>   for that information.

Going by the error message, I renamed my column name to `payment_type` instead of `type`. But I am still getting the same error.

Not able to understand the problem here.

Comment: `self.inheritance_column = nil`

Comment: didn't get you here.

Comment: add it to the class, on which you get the error - it will tell Rails to not look for STI. `class Foo self.inheritance_column = nil end`